# optim function argument missing

Tags: r, optimization

This is my code. The `kum.loglik` function returns negative loglikelihood and takes two arguments a and b. I need to find a and b that minimize this function using optim function. (n1,n2,n3 is pre-specified and passed to optim function.

```
kum.loglik = function(a, b, n1, n2, n3) {
  loglik = n1*log(b*beta(1+2/a,b)) + n2 * log(b*beta(1+2/a,b)-2*b*beta(1+1/a,b)+1) +
    n3 * log(b*beta(1+1/a,b)-b*beta(1+2/a,b))
  return(-loglik)
}
optim(par=c(1,1), kum.loglik, method="L-BFGS-B",
      n1=n1, n2=n2, n3=n3,
      control=list(ndeps=c(5e-4,5e-4)))
```

This code should work well but it gives error message

```
Error in b * beta(1 + 2/a, b) : 'b' is missing
```

What is wrong in this code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is (straight from the optim help):

```
fn: A function to be minimized (or maximized), with first
argument the vector of parameters over which minimization is
to take place.
```

Your `kum.loglik` function needs to take a vector `v` which you pull the parameters out of, e.g.:

`kum.loglik=function(v) { a = v[1]; b = v[2]; ...}`

Answer (score 1):

I always use the following, it gives you the best results

```
p0 <- c(a,b) #example vector of starting values
m <- optim(p0, loglik, method="BFGS", control=list(fnscale=-1, trace=10),
hessian=TRUE, x=data.frame)
#for table of results
rbind(m$par, sqrt(diag(solve(-m$hessian))))
```